# Partitioning an external HD appropriately

Tags: partition, disk

I plan on booting Kali on an external hard drive. My question is partitioning. If you create the 2 partitions for Swap and Root, do i need to create a 3rd partition for storage. From my understanding, the root will take up the whole partition.

Comment: A dedicated partition for swap is not needed. Either provide adequate RAM to awoid swapping entirely, or use a swap file in root.

Answer (score 0):

My habit is to create a swap, a couple of smallish roots, say 10Gb or 20Gb each, and the rest of the disc as a big partition for /home. This way I can install in the first root partition as normal. In time I might want another OS but preserve the data on /home so I simply install the new OS on the second root partition. If something goes wrong with the new install, I revert to the first partition.

Having /home as an independent partition is good old fashioned best practice!

Comment: Kali, like other modern Debian derived distros, does not require a swap partition, and does perfectly fine with their a swap file, or just extra RAM in lieu of swapping.